# Why are MVC3 bin_deployable dlls necessary for webforms application under MVC3 website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I have an webforms application configured under an MVC3 site in IIS 7.5. I'm 'Could not load file or assembly...' exceptions for System.Web.Mvc and System.Web.Helpers. When I add the MVC3 dlls to the webforms application bin directory everything works.

Why do I have to include the bin_deployable dlls in the webforms application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to *"bin deploy"*, unless the server you are deploying it to doesn't have the assemblies in it's GAC (usually true for shared hosting environments).

---

### Update (per comments):

> "I have an webforms application configured under an MVC3 site"

See: [**Web.config inheritance**](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx)

Comment: Right. I know that. Question is why are the dlls necessary at all in the webforms project?

Comment: @Rich hmmm - `"I have an webforms application configured under an MVC3 site"` - is the WebForms app its own virtual directory/application?

Comment: @Rich - See [**web config inheritance**](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/01/17/10-things-asp-net-developers-should-know-about-web-config-inheritance-and-overrides.aspx) hth

Comment: Awesome! That was it. Edit your answer so I can mark it as the answer.